# Specific grid line in X axis in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there a way to place a single grid line at specific XAxis value?

I'm trying to make something like the image linked below:

[image: chart example]

I already setup everything that I need to build it, it is just that damn grid line left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you simply need to create a custom callback on the `xAxes` and return `null` for all the grid lines you want to filter out - leaving the single grid line you require in your chart.

e.g.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
    }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            // where 3 is the line index you want to display
            return (index == 3) ? "" : null;
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fraser/kuwh3nzs/

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what i'm looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: @JoãoLuizAranda - no problem - also note you could filter on `value` too rather than `index` - also if you replace the returned empty string `""` with text, e.g. `return (index == 3) ? "foo" : null;` then your single grid line will be labeled "foo".

Comment: Sure! Thank you again for the tips

Comment: FYI, to filter by value you now need to use this.getLabelForValue(value)  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Comment: Man .. you saved my life. One of the simplest and easiest solution. I wish i could give you 100 votes

Answer (score 0):

The `color` property in the grid has the support JS functions and then using the `context` you can give different colors to different grid lines.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/grid.html

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works for hiding the grid lines in a Line chart.

Set the gridLines color to be the same as the div's background color.

```
var options = {
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        }   
    }]
}
```

}

or use

```
var options = {
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        }   
    }]
}
}
```

Comment: But I need to change the color of the specific line, so I can't set color or display, because it sets all of them